# How to copy a section of a webpage when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now my webpage looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLveT.png) and the grey section is the part I wanted copied when the "Add another file?" is clicked. Similar to this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCHmX.png).

The platform where I'm coding on right now is google apps script so if you could make your answer suitable for GAS it'd be greatly appreciated! thanks! I will put a jsfiddle of my code in the comments

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please put the most relevant code and screenshots *in* your question rather than linking to them.

Comment: Do not put integral parts of your question in the comments. This is Stack Overflow, not Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Position the DOM for the part to be copied in a hidden location.

Then clone it and insert it into the appropriate location as needed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode